# Transparent webm file animation not showing up properly in React/JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webm

I am a front end dev that has a client wanting to display a transparent video in the react app i'm building. Everything she sent me would show up with a black background. I told her to convert her gif/mp4 videos to a webm file since transparency is supported. I've used webm videos before and never had an issue. She sent me a 'final' webm video file and I put it n the JSX of the react app.. it still has a black background. But now they are saying it must be on my end bc they hired a 'professional exporter'. I imported everything as i always do, what is going on? This is my JSX, I have spent time messing around with the keywords too. What is going on and how can I get the transparent video to show up transparent with code?[image]

Comment: Have you been able to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

delete controls option or set to false (constrols={false})

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).